# Comparison operation === not working on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I don't know why, but the code below works in Firefox but NOT in Google Chrome, why ? This should be standard JS.

```
status = parseInt($('#input-status').val());
// status field is exactly equals to 0
if (status === 0) {
// do something, in Firefox the code reaches here, in Chrome NOT !
}
```

Here is how #input-status is defined in html :

```
<input type="hidden" id="input-status" name="input-status" value="00">
```

In Chrome the code works only if i replace === by == .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do `console.log(typeof status);` before the if statement - what does Chrome say the type is?

Comment: Are you sure that chrome parses successfully the string? Cause this is seems to be the problem.

Comment: [I do not think your assessment is correct.](http://jsfiddle.net/UdUss/)

Comment: Don't forget to specify your radix--`parseInt($("#input-status").val(), 10);`

Comment: Chrome says status is string, but if i call parseInt, why it's not integer ?

Comment: @delphirules is that *really* your code *exactly*?

Comment: Yes. Here is my code for input-status field : <input type="hidden" id="input-status" name="input-status" value="00">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens but I can reproduce it like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdhP6/1/)

```
status = parseInt($('#input-status').val(), 10);
test = parseInt($('#input-status').val(), 10);

console.log(typeof status); // string
console.log(typeof test); // number
```

I guess `status` is predefined by the browser and can't be parsed.
To make it work use `var` to define a new variable in the current scope:

```
var status = parseInt($('#input-status').val(), 10);

if (status === 0) {
    // this also works in chrome
}
```

**EDIT**

```
console.log(window.status === status); // true
```

It seems like `status` is a reference to the `window.status` object which changes the status bar in the browser. 
And it does make sense that this can't be parsed into a number.

@Xotic750 pointed out:

> Yes, on Chrome whenever you set the global variable [`status/window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status) to any value `window.status = {}` then it converts it to a string `{value: "[object Object]", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9tvDV/) lesson: don't use global variables, use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to make them locally scoped

Comment: Great, adding 'var' solves it ! :)

Comment: Yes, on Chrome whenever you set the global variable `status`/`window.status` to any value `window.status = {}` then it converts it to a string `{value: "[object Object]", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9tvDV/), lesson: don't use global variables, use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to make them locally scoped.

Comment: Just want to reiterate that the lesson you should take from this is: Never use implicitly defined global variables. Always use var, and don't use globals whenever possible.